# Python Using methods from other modules

Tags: python

I have two modules called Dfs and Graph.
In my Graph module, I have a class Graph and a method called ReadGraph.
In my Dfs module, I have a method that calls on ReadGraph but I get the following error message when I type: Dfs.ProcessGraph(testcase.txt,verbose=True)

Error message:
NameError: name 'testcase' is not defined

Could someone explain how to fix this?

Thanks.

From my Dfs.py module:

```
import sys 
from Graph import *

class Dfs( object ):

   def ProcessGraph(file_name, verbose):
      g=ReadGraph(file_name)
```

From my Graph.py module:

```
class Graph( object ):

   def ReadGraph( file_name ):
```

Comment: Where is you code? Do you `import`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: At the top of my Dfs module I have: from Graph import *

Comment: Can you include a minimal code example that produces the error?

Comment: Is the indentation correct? Are the functions seperate from the classes?

Comment: Everything seems fine. Are they in the same directory?

Comment: @TimCastelijns: The indentation seems right. The functions are part of the class.

Comment: @KrzysztofWende: My testcase.txt, Graph.py, and Dfs.py are all in the same folder.

Comment: You need to procide more of the code.

Comment: @Student if this indentation is right, the functions are not part of the classes, but I had a feeling they were meant to be

Comment: @TimCastelijns: Sorry, I meant that the indentation in my code was correct, but the code I posted above was not. I have now edited my post to reflect what my code is.

Comment: Try this `Dfs.ProcessGraph('testcase.txt',verbose=True)` add a quote before and after `testcase.txt`. Python thinks that `testcase` is an instance or class and `txt` as a method or property

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound: When I type, Dfs.ProcessGraph('testcase.txt',verbose=True), I get this: TypeError: unbound method ProcessGraph() must be called with Dfs instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Comment: @Student You haven't included the `self` argument, but then you don't need any data from the class; why are your "functions" in classes at all?

Comment: @Student add `@staticmethod` on top of the definition for `ProcessGraph`. Python thinks `ProcessGraph` is an instance method, not static method

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound: When I do that I get: global name 'ReadGraph' is not defined

Comment: @Student I checked you're profile and it seems you're familar with Java. Assuming you're applying your knowledge of Java's oop, Python has a different way of declaring class. In Python, the instance object, commonly called `self`, is part of method's parameter whereas in Java `this` is accessible in instance methods, and is implicit. I suggest reading this [link](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html) to get yourself familair with Python's OOP.

Comment: @Student please check my answer, you need to create an instance of Graph in DFs this way you can use all it's methods on the go.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your class declaration from Graph.py. When you import all from a file you get all top level objects. In this case it's the `Graph` class itself, not its methods.

Also you need to pass string `'testcase.txt'` not `testcase.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems here:

1. If you `from Graph import *` (which is bad practice to start with), you bring `Graph` into your name space. However, `ReadGraph` is *inside* `Graph`, so to access it you need `Graph.ReadGraph`.
2. Having done that, you try to call `Dfs.ProcessGraph(testcase.txt,verbose=True)`. The first argument is interpreted as "pass the `txt` attribute of the object referenced by name `testcase`, which doesn't exist. Instead, you mean `"testcase.txt"` (quoted to make it a string).
3. Having done all of that, you get e.g. `TypeError: unbound method ProcessGraph() must be called with Dfs instance as first argument (got str instance instead)`. When you call an instance method, the first argument, `self` by convention, is the instance itself. You have two choices; either a) make e.g. `ProcessGraph` a `@staticmethod`, and access it `Graph.ReadGraph`; or b) move it outside the class, then you can access it directly like you tried to in the first place. As you don't seem to have any class or instance attributes, it's not clear why you are bothering with the classes at all.

What it should probably look like:

```
import sys 

from Graph import read_graph

def process_graph(file_name, verbose):
  g = read_graph(file_name)
```

`Graph.py` module (note absence of `class Graph`):

```
def read_graph(file_name):
    ...
```

(Generally, I suggest you read [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Comment: When I try: from Graph import read_graph, I get: cannot import name ReadGraph

Comment: Yes, when I try compiling Dfs.py I get: ImportError: cannot import name ReadGraph

Comment: What do you mean "compiling"? If your code in Graph.py doesn't define a class or function `ReadGraph` at the top level, you can't import it.

Comment: When I run the module (press F5). My code in Graph.py has a class called Graph and inside the class has a function called ReadGraph.

Comment: Please read the whole of my answer; you can't `from Graph import ReadGraph` if `ReadGraph` is *inside* the class `Graph`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51405/discussion-between-student-and-jonrsharpe)

Answer (score 0):

your code should be : `Dfs.ProcessGraph('testcase.txt',verbose=True)`
and not `Dfs.ProcessGraph(testcase.txt,verbose=True)`

```
'testcase.txt' # is a string and should be between quotes
```

also check if it is in the same directory where your code live else point to it

plus in DFs you should instantiate Graph :

```
from Graph.Graph import *
g = Graph()
grf = g.ReadGraph('filename')
```

EDIT: to be more precise

in Graph module:

```
class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass # for the example now

    def read_graph(self, file_name):
        return file_name
```

in Dfs Module:

```
from Graph import *
class Dfs(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass # for the example now

    def ProcessGraph(file_name, verbose):
        g  = Graph()
        file_name = Graph.read_graph(file_name)
```

Comment: `g.ReadGraph('filename')` won't work without adding the `self` argument or `@staticmethod` decorator.